# jQuery - select parent and hide

Tags: jquery, hide, parent

I have a row of items with a close X float right. I want to have the entire row get hidden (well, removed, so not sure if there is something for that?) when the X is clicked.

However, it doesn't work for me. It is seemingly simple code, so not sure where I am going wrong. I even took the EXACT code from this question: [jQuery - Can't hide parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874438/jquery-cant-hide-parent). And it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/2kYrU/9/

HTML:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='close'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {   
    background:black;        
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;                
}

.close {
    background:red;            
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    float:right;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.close').click(function(){

        $(this).parent.().hide();
    });

});
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have an extra dot after $(this).parent. Always watch your error console. It can save you a lot of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$(this).parent.().hide();
              ^
```

Remove that dot and everything works: http://jsfiddle.net/2kYrU/11/

Answer (score 2):

**Two things:**

There is a type in the way you are referencing parent

```
//You have
$(this).parent.().hide();  
//Should be the following
$(this).parent().hide();
```

Also when you are using JSFiddle you need to change the framework to the one you would like you use on the left panel.  You had mootools selected not JQuery so none of your JQuery script would work.

[image]